# ADB starting activity with extra string data

Tags: android, powershell, android-intent, adb

I am executing the following from ADB:

```
PS C:\> adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n boha.notify/.MainActivity -e primaryheader "One Two" -e primarytext "Primary text"
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN pkg=Two cmp=boha.notify/.MainActivity (has extras) }
Warning: Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front
PS C:\>
```

My application is setup to properly handle the new intent request without restarting the already running activity. I've overridden `onNewIntent()` as required. It's shown below:

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent)
{
    super.onNewIntent(intent);

    Log.d( "AGENT", "NEW INTENT Extra data = " + intent.getStringExtra("primaryheader"));

    String strPrimaryHeader = intent.getStringExtra("primaryheader");
    String strPrimaryText = intent.getStringExtra("primarytext");
    String strSecondayHeader = intent.getStringExtra("secondaryheader");
    String strSecondaryText = intent.getStringExtra("secondarytext");
}
```

When I check the `logcat` I see that the extra data strings I'm passing in aren't being received correctly. Only the first word of each string is correct.

See below:

`09-13 18:30:36.583 12248-12248/? D/AGENT: NEW INTENT Extra data = One`

Why is the activity new intent only receiving "One" instead of "One Two"?

Am I not using the correct ADB `am` command parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have explained the root cause multiple times before. It's because you have multiple sub shells. And when the outer shell (in your case `powershell`) parses the command it eats the `"` (i.e. uses them for properly splitting the command into separate command line parameters). But this information (that your multi word string is a single parameter) gets lost by the time the command reaches the inner shell (the `/bin/sh` of your android device). So as the result it launches the `am` command with every word being a separate parameter.

The easiest way to mitigate that is to double-quote the whole `adb shell` subcommand and use single quotes for the internal strings:

```
PS C:\> adb shell "am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n boha.notify/.MainActivity -e primaryheader 'One Two' -e primarytext 'Primary text'"
```

Comment: Thank you. That makes a lot of sense. When I get a chance to try it, I will likely accept your answer.

Comment: That seems to be the way to enclose everything. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

Use `--es` for string extras

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n boha.notify/.MainActivity --es primaryheader "One Two" --es primarytext "Primary text"
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried that. Seems to work if I do this `-e primarytext "'Primary Text'"` Seems a multi word string needs to be enclosed in ' '

Comment: Unusual... could also try added a mime type after each string? ```-t "text/plain"```

Comment: Thanks again. That doesn't work either. It's weird that I have to add ' ' around strings.